# What is a offset in a binary file header in c?

Tags: c

I am reading in a binary file which has a fileheader, and then different sections of information, each of those sections also has a section header. First I read the file header, and in the header it has something called a section offset, which says "the offset of the section header table".

This is probably a pretty simple question but what does offset mean?

Comment: In this context probably `Amount of bytes to be read before you get to the section header table`.

Comment: offset in general means the number of bytes after a certain point. But what it means exactly for your context depends on format of the file. But whatever the format of the file it is likely to have documentation which will answer your question precisely so go read it. For example, if your file is an ELF binary then the doc is [here](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/elf.pdf) and says: "The ELF header's e_shoff  member gives the byte offset from 
the beginning of the file to the section header table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's the n number of bytes from one place to some other place in the file.

This could actually mean different things for different file formats:

Eg, the offset of the data after the beginning of the section header,
Or, the offset from of that section from the beginning of the file,
Etc...etc....

You're going to have to check the spec for the file format that you're using.